# Ethers.js is not returning the full object struct from mapping

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

I have this struct

`struct User { Counters.Counter total; mapping(uint => address) payment_splitters; }`

And this mapping

`mapping(uint => address) payment_splitters;`

As far as I understand, this is the correct way to get a user from payment_splitters mapping.

`const user = await myContract.payment_splitters_registry(userAddress);`

The problem is that I am just getting one element from the struct, which is `total`.

What do you think I'm missing from ethersjs? Why I only get one element from my struct?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong as I notice,
You can define a mapping for accesing users like this in you soldiity code:

```
/** mapping of userId to User Struct */
mapping(uint256 => User) public users;
```

fill users mapping in your function.

and in your js code, you can access user struct like this:

```
const user = await myContract.users(userId);
```